# How do I execute raw SQL in a django migration

Tags: django, postgresql, database-partitioning, django-migrations

I am aware of the cursor object in Django. Is there any other preferred way to execute raw SQL in migrations? I want to introduce postgresql partitioning for one of my models tables. The partition logic is a bunch of functions and triggers that have to be added to the database on setup which I'd like to automate.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

## One way:

The best way I found to do this is using RunSQL:

Migrations contains the RunSQL class. To do this:

1. `./manage.py makemigrations --empty myApp`
2. edit the created migrations file to include:

`operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL('RAW SQL CODE')
]`

As Nathaniel Knight mentioned, `RunSQL` also accepts a `reverse_sql` parameter for reversing the migration. [See the docs for details](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/migration-operations/#runsql)

## Another way

The way I solved my problem initially was using the `post_migrate` signal to call a cursor to execute my raw SQL.

What I had to add to my app was this:

in the `__init__.py` of myApp add:

```
default_app_config = 'myApp.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

Create a file `apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate
from myApp.db_partition_triggers import create_partition_triggers


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myApp'
    verbose_name = "My App"

    def ready(self):
        post_migrate.connect(create_partition_triggers, sender=self)
```

New file `db_partition_triggers.py`:

```
from django.db import connection


def create_partition_triggers(**kwargs):
    print '  (re)creating partition triggers for myApp...'
    trigger_sql = "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION...; IF NOT EXISTS(...) CREATE TRIGGER..."
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(trigger_sql)
    print '  Done creating partition triggers.'
```

Now on every `manage.py syncdb` or `manage.py migrate` this function is called. So make sure it uses `CREATE OR REPLACE` and `IF NOT EXISTS`. So it can handle existing functions.

Comment: Is there a way to add backwards-migration for suctom sql?

Comment: You should really move your note about RunSQL to the top. It's absolutely the best way to do this...

Comment: @DataGreed Not sure if you still want to know, but you can pass a 2nd SQL string to be used as the reverse sql.

Comment: Note that RunSQL requires installation of the sqlparse library.

Comment: For the record, `RunSQL` also accepts a `reverse_sql` parameter for reversing the migration. See the docs for details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/migration-operations/#runsql

Comment: I want to manually add a complex constraint in a Postgresql table with RunSQL (not natively supported by Django). How do I get my SQL query to run after the other operations (notably after the creation of all tables)?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend **django-migrate-sql-deux** https://pypi.org/project/django-migrate-sql-deux/

This way you can manage database objects like views, functions, triggers in declarative way like models in Django. Then you need generate changes into Django migrations through `makemigrations`. And apply them via `migrate`. So the development and deploy flow is pretty same.

It would be awesome if Django would have this system for raw SQL "models" and handle migrations and dependencies automatically in `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands like *django-migrate-sql-deux*.